# c# accessing Outlook calendar from a custom Excel add-in

Tags: c#, excel, outlook, add-in

Is it possible to create an add-in for Excel which accesses/imports a calendar from Outlook?  I am using c# in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible - Excel Add-In is a DLL library and you can do almost everything there. (I believe you already seen the MSDN page about developing add-ins: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157876.aspx). On the Outlook side, it is a bit more complicated, but Calendar folder is accessible via Outlook Interop and folder hierarchy. See http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=310244 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder.aspx

HTH